# Как передать значение в пост через инпут?

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="news" value="{$content.name}">
</form>
```

Попробую сформировать вопрос.

Вопрос стоит в том, что мне нужно выдать контент на страницу по id из БД. В значение value у меня название статьи, по клику которой должна отобразиться  вся статья. Как мне передать id в пост если  value у меня занят названием статьи? (По названию статьи не могу дергать из БД  так как название могут повторяться). В JS. слаб.

Comment: value="<?= $content.name ?>" В пост передастся название статьи. а мне нужен id но при этом value должно остаться название статьи.

Comment: [Элементов формы](https://webref.ru/course/html-content/forms) может быть сколько-угодно. Никто не ограничивает вас в добавлении, например, скрытого поля с именем `news_id` и значением `value`, соответствующим ID конкретной статьи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$content.id}">
 <input type="submit" name="news" value="{$content.name}">
</form>
```